# Free foley / sound effect sites? 

Tags: foley, sound-effects, websites, royalty-free

Hey guys, I was wondering if any of you might know good websites that offer free sound effects similar to http://www.freesound.org/? I stumbled upon this few years back when I was studying in polytechnic school and have used it a lot ever since. If you haven´t used freesound.org, check it out it´s awesome!

Ville

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the terms of use for freesound.org, its mostly not useable for anything commercial...

FWIW Foley is performed to picture, its not something you 'download for free'

Comment: Preach on, brother!...This drives me so nuts. I have producers who actually say things like, "Don't you have the sound of a man putting on a jacket in that big SFX drive thingy"  or even "Do you want us to just throw the cymbals on the open title for you in edit and set volume levels...it might save you time, right?"  They usually have never experienced foley, custom design, or real audio post.  After a small plee to let me have a few hours to give them what I know will make them happier, they are usually the most impressed. But sadly... more frustrating to work with.    

Comment: I hear you there...

Answer (score 2):

You can get some free stuff at [AudioMicro](http://www.audiomicro.com/) they don't sound very high quality but its better than nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the pro libraries give out free samples of their audio packs e.g.

http://hissandaroar.com/free-sounds/ in 16bit 44.1kHz

All it requires is an email address then you get a download link to be used within an hour.

But don't forget to get out there and record some yourself!

Answer (score 2):

You need to be really careful with the licensing of "free" sounds - they usually demand formatted credit in specific ways.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.soundjay.com/

Few gigs of high quality sound efffects for free, terms of use as followed:

"Sound Effects
You are allowed to use the sounds free of charge and royalty free in your projects (such as films, videos, games, presentations, animations, stage plays, radio plays, audio books, apps) be it for commercial or non-commercial purposes."

http://www.soundmorph.com/index.php?page=free

"All CONTENT in this product is licensed, but not sold, to you by SoundMorph. for commercial and non-commercial use in music, sound-effect, audio/video post-production, performance, broadcast or similar finished content-creation and production use."

http://www.blastwavefx.com/Free-SFX-Download-Pack-%231/t3/articles.html

"You have the right to synchronize the audio content from any Blastwave FX royalty free product with audio and/or visual productions or applications such as: film & video productions - training and marketing presentations - corporate videos - on hold messages - radio presentations or commercials - television presentations or commercials - musical recordings - live performances - Web pages - multimedia presentations - interactive programs - computer games - audio-visual or computer generated displays, programs or presentations which may incorporate streaming audio or podcasts (hereinafter referred to as "the Production")."

Answer (score 0):

I've got a few good samples from Freesound in the past but if you're looking for something like Footsteps the quality is pretty terrible.
I'm not sure of free alternatives besides recording things yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Freesound has introduced a feature that lets users search for Creative Commons 0 (Public Domain, that is) sounds: http://www.freesound.org/search/?q=&f=license%3A%22Creative+Commons+0%22&s=score+desc&advanced=0&g=1

Thought it might be helpful.

Comment: This is a pretty cool feature! Thanks for mentioning it.